# What gives you the better perfomance? C# : Const Vs Normal fields -in FOR loop fields declaration

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I would like to know which gives us a better performs on both the ways as given below:

**1. Way 1**

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
> {
>    // do something in loop
> }
> ```

**2. Way 2**

> ```
> for(int i = Constants.Zero; i < Constants.Ten; i++)
> {
>     // do something in loop
> }
> ```

```
private const int Zero = 0; 

private const int Ten = 10;
```

Basically I want to know that Can we increase the application performance if we use `Constants` in `for loop variable declaration` as mentioned above?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I understand this is just sample code, but I do hope you use more meaningful constant names in your production code. :)

Comment: I know you are just posting an example, but why on earth would you use a constant for zero?

Comment: [If only there were a way to test this out...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Comment: Make sure that we have used FOR loop around 200 places with normal field initialized and if we replace all with CONSTANTS, we found less memory occupied with them. I wasn't sure about this on performance wise, that is the reason I posted it here.

Comment: There is no difference for value types. In this case, the start and end values get into the stack and are stored until the loop is done. the only thing that changes during the loop is the incremental value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *any* performance benefit here, as variable declared in that way will end up into injected constants, like in your first case. So they are become basically the same.

```
//code 1
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}

//IL 1

IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  br.s        IL_0016
IL_0005:  nop         
IL_0006:  ldstr       "Hello"
IL_000B:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0010:  nop         
IL_0011:  nop         
IL_0012:  ldloc.0     
IL_0013:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0014:  add         
IL_0015:  stloc.0     
IL_0016:  ldloc.0     
IL_0017:  ldc.i4.s    0A 
IL_0019:  clt         
IL_001B:  stloc.1     
IL_001C:  ldloc.1     
IL_001D:  brtrue.s    IL_0005

//code 2
for(int i = Constants.Zero; i < Constants.Ten; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}

//IL 2
IL_0001:  ldsfld      UserQuery+Constants.Zero
IL_0006:  stloc.0     
IL_0007:  br.s        IL_001A
IL_0009:  nop         
IL_000A:  ldstr       "Hello"
IL_000F:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0014:  nop         
IL_0015:  nop         
IL_0016:  ldloc.0     
IL_0017:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0018:  add         
IL_0019:  stloc.0     
IL_001A:  ldloc.0     
IL_001B:  ldsfld      UserQuery+Constants.Ten
IL_0020:  clt         
IL_0022:  stloc.1     
IL_0023:  ldloc.1     
IL_0024:  brtrue.s    IL_0009
```

In *second* case I used a `static` class to create constants.

Comment: Are you sure that your constants are actually declared as `const` in the second example? If they are then I'd expect the IL to be *exactly* the same as the first example, and not have those `ldsfld` instructions in there.

Comment: @LukeH: no, naturally cause its a static class, so they are declared as *readonly*.

Comment: Yes.. they are declared as an actual constant. (with const keyword)

Comment: @Tigran: `const` and `readonly` are completely different: if you use `const` then those constant values are "injected" into any code that uses them; if you use `readonly` then the values must be loaded from the fields each time, assuming that the jitter doesn't do any optimisation magic. So, your IL example actually contradicts your (correct) explanatory paragraph.

Comment: @LukeH: the resultin `IL`s apparently does the same thing in *this* case. *May be*, cause there JIT optimization applied here. But the *result* is the same, as in case of constants. I just tried to do the different solution then simple `const` to check if it produces same behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

There is no performance difference. The compiled `for` loop will be exactly the same in both cases.

The constants are "burned into" the compiled code, just as if you'd used literal values.

(And I'm assuming that this is just a toy example: otherwise why would you want to replace perfectly good, universally recognised symbols -- `0`, `10`, etc -- with your own versions that aren't widely known?)